# How to change the color of active link dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hyperlink

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  font-size: 20px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}


.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

/* Right-aligned section inside the top navigation */
.topnav-right {
  float: right;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
  <h2><center>CAMPUS RECRUITMENT SYSTEM</center></h2>
  <!--   <p>**Single stop for all your recruitment destinations.</p>   -->
</div>

<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a></li>
  <div class="topnav-right">
  <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
  <li><a href="admin.php">Admin</a></li>
</div>
</ul>




</body>
</html>
```

Please check the code and help me to change the color of active link dynamically. I don't know how to do that. I have tried to add some java script code but it didn't worked.

Comment: when do you want to change it? On what moment, event,..?

Comment: where is your javascript then?

Comment: when linked on one link that link will be active and until another link is slicked that link must be active with some color.

Comment: `document.querySelector('a.active').style.color = 'red';`

Comment: @Mamum Please help

Comment: From deleted answer comment: *"When I removed the line return flase; then the functionality stopped working and when that line is present in code then the link color is changing but the page is not loading*" - see the "discussion" here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60393417/link-clicks-no-longer-redirect-page-when-adding-class-to-element#comment106835905_60393417.

Comment: tl;dr - you're not asking the correct question / not describing what you want properly.

Comment: @freedomn-m I have provided my code above I want to change the color og active link dynamically.

Comment: As discussed on that other question: no, you don't.  You were given code for that then complained that *"the link colour is changing but the page is not loading"* - you're trying to set the colour, then redirect - **redirecting resets the colour** - so no, you don't want to *just* change the colour of the active link.

Comment: @freedomn-n when you click a link of course page related to that link will open. But the active link must also be color changed until some other link  is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically change the color of the `a` tag with `active` class in JS like:

```
document.querySelector('a.active').style.color = 'red';
```

But for your specific need it's better to do it in css with active pseudo class:

```
a:active {
  background-color: red;  /* choose your color here */
}
```